# Is it possible to test the android native apks like camera, music player using robotium

Tags: robotium

How to test the inbuilt android apks like camera, calculator, gallery using robotium?
I have tried but am getting error like `does not have a signature matching the target`. Is it possible to test the inbuilt apks using robotium?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no. For testing native Android apps try to use `uiatomator` test framework. Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator